# Can I port mdadm volumes to hardware raid?

Tags: raid, mdadm, software-raid

> Can I port mdadm volumes to hardware raid?

I'm retiring an old server which uses mdadm volumes but the volumes are coming onto the new server which has hardware raid capability.  Can I plug the disks and go or will I need to cp everything over?  The disks are fine and the content is still required.

Comment: What kind of RAID is this? AFAIK, MD RAID and hardware raid have little in common.

Comment: In general, no. It works better the other way around. Even then it requires careful planning or a lot of trial & error.

Comment: Contrary to other comments, RAID protocol is consistent whether applied through software or hardware.  That said, there are many details that do depend on the implementation and would make this task almost impossible.  You should copy everything over.

Comment: @FaheemMitha it's md

Comment: @RobertFrost No, I mean is it eg RAID 1, RAID 5?

Comment: @FaheemMitha just Raid 1. The new server has a PERC controller. Seems to make most sense to mount one of the old disks direct to the BIOS and mount it using mdadm, and the other to the PERC controller, wipe it a copy over the data. Then mount the 2nd one to PERC controller.

Comment: RAID is just mirroring, so transfering the data to hardware RAID should not be a problem. I'm puzzled that you are asking. One of the disks has all the data, just stick it into the hardware raid and let it mirror. (This does assume that MD RAID does mirroring transparently, which I admit I have not checked.) However, personally I'd stick with software raid. MD RAID is quite reliable, and I hardware raid cards are very expensive and can die. I had one once; it was a high end RAID card, but it died. I don't see the advantage of Hardware RAID over software RAID personally.

Comment: @FaheemMitha The hardware RAID claims to erase all data from the source disk when you add a volume

Comment: Hi @RobertFrost. I'm not sure what you mean. If you like, we can talk about it in the general chat room (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat), but if you don't have an issue, don't feel obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoftRaid and Hardware raid have nothing than "conceptual" common things related to redundancy.

There isn't a magical tool that could strip mdadm peculiarities, since with hardware raid(not fakeraid) a disk will be presented to you as `/dev/sdX` and not 2 or more disks to be configured as `/dev/mdX`to be managed by the kernel.

You will have to sync data between disks.